# Chromatic Coloring Problem

Tags: graph-theory

The vertices of $G$ are colored with three colors in such a way that each vertex
is adjacent to vertices colored with only one of the three colors. Show that
$\chi(G)\neq3$. What does this say if $\chi(G) = 3$?

Comment: By "colored with three colors" I guess you mean "**properly** colored with three colors", i.e., adjacent vertices never have the same color? Otherwise, I can get a counterexample by taking a graph of chromatic number $3$ and coloring all of its vertices red.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Recall that a graph is bipartite if and only if there are no odd cycles.

That's assuming the hypothesis was supposed to say properly colored. I guess the second question is just asking you to write the contrapositive of the statement?